# Linq - Subquery count

Tags: linq

**Problem:** Am trying to rewrite this in Linq:

listOfUsersForReviewer is an `IEnumerable<User>`

```
int countOfGreenUsers = 0;
foreach (var user in listOfUsersForReviewer)
{
    var u = (from reviewitems in context.ReviewItems
                join groupaccountlinks in context.GroupAccountLinks on reviewitems.GroupAccountID equals groupaccountlinks.GroupAccountID
                join reviews in context.Reviews on reviewitems.ReviewID equals reviews.ReviewID
                join applications in context.Applications on reviews.ApplicationID equals applications.ApplicationID
                join reviewers in context.Reviewers on applications.ResponsibleReviewerID equals reviewers.ReviewerID
                join accounts in context.Accounts on groupaccountlinks.AccountID equals accounts.AccountID
                join users in context.RBSUsers on accounts.UserID equals users.UserID
                where
                    users.UserID == user.UserID &&
                    reviewers.FullyQualifiedLogin == fullyQualifiedLogin &&
                    reviews.ReviewStatusID == (byte)Enums.ReviewStatus.InProgress &&
                    reviewitems.ReviewItemStatusID == (byte)Enums.ReviewItemStatus.Unapproved
                select reviewitems);

    byte colour = (byte)Enums.UserStatusColour.Red;
    if (u.Count() == 0)
    {
        colour = (byte)Enums.UserStatusColour.Green;
        countOfGreenUsers++;
    }
}
```

have tried to create an anonymous type, however this doesn't compile.

```
// select number of green users
var x = from user in listOfUsersForReviewer
        from reviewitems in context.ReviewItems
        join groupaccountlinks in context.GroupAccountLinks on reviewitems.GroupAccountID equals
            groupaccountlinks.GroupAccountID
        join reviews in context.Reviews on reviewitems.ReviewID equals reviews.ReviewID
        join applications in context.Applications on reviews.ApplicationID equals applications.ApplicationID
        join reviewers in context.Reviewers on applications.ResponsibleReviewerID equals
            reviewers.ReviewerID
        join accounts in context.Accounts on groupaccountlinks.AccountID equals accounts.AccountID
        join users in context.RBSUsers on accounts.UserID equals users.UserID
        where
            users.UserID == user.UserID &&
            reviewers.FullyQualifiedLogin == fullyQualifiedLogin &&
            reviews.ReviewStatusID == (byte)Enums.ReviewStatus.InProgress &&
            reviewitems.ReviewItemStatusID == (byte)Enums.ReviewItemStatus.Unapproved
        select new
            {
                UserID = user.UserID,
                CountOfGreen = reviewitems.Count()
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rethinking me logic and split this query into 2 simpler ones.

Tools I used were:  SQL Server Management Studio (graphical representation), [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) and potentially [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

And writing the query in English helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add grouping clause

```
var x = from user in listOfUsersForReviewer
        from reviewitems in context.ReviewItems
        join groupaccountlinks in context.GroupAccountLinks on reviewitems.GroupAccountID equals
            groupaccountlinks.GroupAccountID
        join reviews in context.Reviews on reviewitems.ReviewID equals reviews.ReviewID
        join applications in context.Applications on reviews.ApplicationID equals applications.ApplicationID
        join reviewers in context.Reviewers on applications.ResponsibleReviewerID equals
            reviewers.ReviewerID
        join accounts in context.Accounts on groupaccountlinks.AccountID equals accounts.AccountID
        join users in context.RBSUsers on accounts.UserID equals users.UserID
        where
            users.UserID == user.UserID &&
            reviewers.FullyQualifiedLogin == fullyQualifiedLogin &&
            reviews.ReviewStatusID == (byte)Enums.ReviewStatus.InProgress &&
            reviewitems.ReviewItemStatusID == (byte)Enums.ReviewItemStatus.Unapproved
        group user by user.UserID into grouping
        select new
            {
                UserID = grouping.Key,
                CountOfGreen = grouping.Count()
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tt is bringing back the correct result, however performance is bad - taking minutes to run.  I've got listOfUsersForReviewer iterated in memory (.ToList())

Comment: Thanks Tilak - it was more the subquery I suspect.